# Hover on dotted border not covering the whole border

Tags: css, hover, border

I have a white border that should turn to red on hover (which it does) but the red part doesn't cover the complete white dotted line for some reason. Can anybody guide me in the right direction?

View the site for more details:
[Website](http://i-bay.co.za/hamiltons/works/)

Comment: What browser are you using? It's working fine in chrome.

Comment: Er... what? You need to narrow down your problem to a specific part of that page, or even better, post a [JSFiddle](http://jsfiddle.net) demonstrating your problem

Comment: The issue is visible in firefox, it's like in normal state the border is longer than hovering it...

Comment: Sorry people. The issue is only occurring in Firefox, yes. When hovering over any of the portfolio items.

Answer (score 0):

Try using the hover state on the .post-item

```
.post-item:hover .item-footer {border-top:3px dotted red;}
.post-item:hover .overlay {opacity:0.5;}
```

And use css-transitions to animate the change

here is an example

http://codepen.io/anon/pen/gKqrh

Comment: I tested this example and it works fine in Chrome, but in Firefox half of the first dot remains black still while the rest turns red.

Comment: It looks like its a bug in Firefox it's more apparent when you enlarge the dots

http://codepen.io/anon/pen/otGau